# Не срабатывает обработчик Select, который задает отображение элемента по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не срабатывает кейс 'default', который должен в select делать значение по умолчанию

```
  ActionWithClassByName = (name, action) => {
    var classForAction = $( "." + name );

    switch (action) {
      case 'hide':
        classForAction.css("display", "none");
        break;

      case 'default':
        classForAction.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        break;

      case 'empty':
        classForAction.val("");
        break;
    }
  }
```

Пробовал также и такой вариант:

```
$( "." + name + " select option:eq(0)").prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`case 'default':`
сработает, если name ===  'default'
возможно вам нужно default значение в switch?

```
switch (action) {
      case 'hide':
        classForAction.css("display", "none");
        break;

      case 'empty':
        classForAction.val("");
        break;
     default:
        classForAction.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        break;
    }
```